# Workbox and responsive images

Tags: image, responsive, workbox

I don't fully understand how responsive images work. so if it doesn't work like I think it does then you can go on and ignore this question. If not here goes.

To ask this question let me paint a picture where a developer uses the workbox precache to cache a series of images in the service worker and since the developer wants to make his webapp responsive. He has to make sure that every image comes in different sizes some large, some medium and others small and all these images he would have to cache since its easy(You just use the glob pattern). but here is the problem. Lets say a user using a smartphone would visit the app and end up using only the medium sized image. so that means that the large image and the small one are useless to that user and he just wasted some important bandwidths caching them. And this would apply to all the other images in the app that are responsive. So the question is if there is a way(an that is a very big if) for workbox to use media queries to know the images to cache for the user based on the user's device. Maybe delay the installation of the service worker for a few milliseconds in order to verify at what dimension the user's device displays the images and so caches those images which the user will use and then discard the rest.